# How to get?sort descending order between dataframes using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My goal here is to print the descending order between dataframe.
I have 5 dataframe and each has column "Quantity". I need to calculate the sum of this column"Quantity" in each dataframe and wish to print the result in decending order in terms of dataframe.

```
df1:

order    quantity
 A         1
 B         4
 C         3
 D         2

df2:

order    quantity
 A         1
 B         4
 C         4
 D         2

df3:

order    quantity
 A         1
 B         4
 C         1
 D         2

df4:

order    quantity
 A         1
 B         4
 C         1
 D         2

df5:

 order    quantity
  A         1
  B         4
  C         1
  D         1
```

my desired result
descending order :

```
df2,df1,df3,df4,df5
```

here df3 and df4 are equal and it can be in anyway.

suggestion please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sorted` with custom sorted lambda function:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
dfs = sorted(dfs, key=lambda x: -x['quantity'].sum())
#another solution
#dfs = sorted(dfs, key=lambda x: x['quantity'].sum(), reverse=True)
```

---

```
print (dfs)
[  order  quantity
0     A         1
1     B         4
2     C         4
3     D         2,   order  quantity
0     A         1
1     B         4
2     C         3
3     D         2,   order  quantity
0     A         1
1     B         4
2     C         1
3     D         2,   order  quantity
0     A         1
1     B         4
2     C         1
3     D         2,   order  quantity
0     A         1
1     B         4
2     C         1
3     D         1]
```

EDIT:

```
dfs = {'df1':df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3, 'df4': df4, 'df5': df5}
dfs = [i for i, j in sorted(dfs.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1]['quantity'].sum())]
print (dfs)
['df2', 'df1', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5']
```

Comment: I need only the name of the dataframe. like `df2,df1,df3,df4,df5`. Whether ur code do that ?.

Comment: @i1100362 - You can create dictioanry of Dataframes and then sorted, check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` method to sort a dataframe list and `sum` to get the sum of a column

```
dfs = [df2,df1,df3,df4,df5]
sorted_dfs = sorted(dfs, key=lambda df: df.quantity.sum(), reverse=True)
```

*Edit:- to print only the name sorted dataframe*

```
df_map = {"df1": df1, "df2":df2, "df3":df3, "df4":df4}
sorted_dfs = sorted(df_map.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1].quantity.sum(), reverse=True)
print(list(x[0] for x in sorted_dfs))
```

Comment: I need only the name of the dataframe. like `df2,df1,df3,df4,df5`. Whether ur code do that ?.

Comment: Have you defined the name of dataframe like `df.name = "some_name"?

Comment: nope. I just done like df1=df.concat() or df2=data.parse('sheet1.xlsx')

Comment: then you may need a map of df_name vs df. Is that ok??

Comment: No problem. So what I wanna do here ?